# FFMpeg, rtsp cameras and series of bad frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video, camera

I have a problem with ffmpeg and rtsp cameras, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

- Sometimes I get a series of damaged frames. It is not a problem related to the camera.
- The date and time is unreadable and the problem happens with different vendors of camera, with different PCs and in different places.
- With the official software the live feed is perfect.

I'm trying with the latest ffmpeg source (5.0.1) in a Debian 11 machine. I'm particularly interested in this problem because I have written a program based on the ffpmeg library and I'm have the same problem (using ffmpeg as library), in both Windows and Linux.

This is the command line to record

```
./ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.11:554/onvif1 a.avi
```

What can I do to resolve this?

I have tried the last ffmpeg as executable with this command line

```
./ffmpeg -i rtsp://...:554/...?... -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 img%03d.png
```

and the problem still exists so the problem is not related to my own implementation.
I have written directly to a ffmpeg developer without response.
Has someone got experience with live555 library?
http://www.live555.com/

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. We are thinking to change the library.

Comment: And you? Have you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately.